# How do you pronounce $\Sigma^+$ or $\Sigma^\dagger$ (as used in Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse)?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm referring to the pronunciation of the $+$ and $\dagger$ notations.

Is it simply pronounced as ‘sigma plus’, or ‘pseudoinverse of sigma’, or ‘sigma pseudoinversed/pseudoinverted’?

Sometimes it is also written with a dagger ($\dagger$) instead of a $+$ in the ‘exponent’, which would then be pronounced ‘sigma dagger’?

After a quick look in the [Linear Algebra section of the Handbook for Spoken Mathematics](http://s22318.tsbvi.edu/mathproject/appB.asp?s=10#main) I still haven't found the way to say a superscripted dagger or plus symbol.

This is not actual maths, but more how to read this or tell somebody when talking about this subject. Thus, I thought I'd ask here, because math has its own language and there actually is a pronunciation tag.

Comment: I might add that the dagger is also called an "obelisk".

Comment: Questions of pronunciation are on topic: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/questions-about-how-to-read-mathematical-notation